# How to stop user location in a scrollView

Tags: swift, location, scrollview

I am developing a 1 view app with a scroll view, to reveal 2 screen upon sliding left and right!!, until here everything is ok...

1st screen contain some images and other labels.
2nd screen a map view which shows the user location and reverse geocoding information, I managed to activate !!!

The question is: How do I stop the location from running on the background when I swipe back to screen 1. I assume that there must be a function that I can apply to the secondView.swift to cancel the location manager so I can save battery!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Carlos and welcome to SO! In your second view I assume you have a `CLLocationManager`. So there's a method that is called every time a view controller is dismissed called `viewWillDisappear` and here you can invalidate your location manager by calling `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()`. It would look like this all together

```
class SecondView, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //set up view, get user location, show on map, etc.
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

}
```

Another option is just to do this as soon as you get the user's location.

Comment: This is what I suspected, however it doesn't work , the console make a remark: override func viewWillDisappear() {
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }"method does not override any method from its superclass" ;and I can't figure out why. thank you anyway pbush25

Comment: is the location icon on the status bar supposed to be removed once this view has disappear ? in my case stays on... Thank again

Comment: Are you using a `UIViewController`?

Comment: I fix the syntax error like : override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }, it remove the error however Im not sure if its working since the location icon (triangle) is still visible in the screen 1 of the app, im not sure if it is because I set the app to access the location while in use of the app in the info.plist. thanks pbush25

Comment: Sorry about the syntax, forgot you had just started. Well if this isn't working you can try to tell the location manager to stop updating in the function where you get the location. That was as soon as  you get the location the manager will be invalidated until you tell it to get locations again.